# SQL Query: returning if column contains substring

Tags: sql, string, inner-join, sql-like

I have two tables tableA and tableB.

I want to write a query where it displays name and id if the string value of tableA's id is a
substring of tableB's name.
I tried the like operator but can't seem to get it to work.

```
   tableA
id   |
bob
cat
sky
   tableB
name   |
bobby
catlyn
bret

answer table
id     |name   | 
bob    bobby
cat    catlyn
```

Comment: post your `tried` query too. and dbms.

Comment: What engine is it?

Comment: also this is not a proper way to handle data. you should have keys to bind the table.

Comment: What is exactly "doesn't work"? Your results are not the same as you've expected? So provide your query and it's output. If you have an error, then add the error message as plain text.

Comment: This was just an example data. I tried something like this "where tableB like %tableA.id%". But this doesn't work as it is not a string value and using + to concatenate doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on a `like` condition:

```
select a.id, b.name
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on b.name like '%' || a.id || '%'
```

You did not tell which database you are running, so this uses standard string concatenation operator `||`; some databases use something else (eg: MySQL and SQLServer have function `concat()`).